# Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib (LoadError) whem trying to run mongosqld in Mac M1

Tags: mongodb, macos, openssl, homebrew, mongodb-biconnector

The error is showing whenever I try to launch mongosqld.

I know the Question is repetitive. But what I've tried I'm showing.

Error showing in terminal is this:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <D7CD9CBA-9A7D-35DA-A053-8ACA1C7DB435> /usr/local/bin/mongosqld
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      mongosqld
```

I tried recommenmded solutions..

```
brew install openssl@1.1
brew link openssl@1.1 --force
```

**Still error persists.**

**Brew config file**:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.6.13
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 747829334b4bb3ab0d67a4c8bd9f4bf78c491c49
Last commit: 3 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: b3eef87fdbfea4c732bd31b0e373ca4f09718670
Core tap last commit: 6 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 14.0.0 build 1400
Git: 2.37.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.84.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 13.0.1-arm64
CLT: 14.1.0.0.1.1666437224
Xcode: 14.1
Rosetta 2: false
```

Comment: Can you add `brew config` and `brew doctor`

Comment: @chenrui I just added brew config.

Comment: Try updating the PATH environment variable to include `openssl@1.1`

Comment: something like this "export BREW_PATH=`brew --prefix`; export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$BREW_PATH/lib:$BREW_PATH/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1s/lib";"